# How to access HTTP request information from another class than the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was wondering something. In ASP.NET we can have Inside aspx page something like this :

```
string ref = Request["ref"];
```

We can have the same thing going in code behind Inside the load of our page with the same type of request.

But is it possible to retreive this value in a C# class (admiting something like toto.cs) ?

Because a Request won't work on a .cs, we already supose to be in the serveur side.

So how would it be done ?.

Edit :

seeing answer and comment, I should have had that toto.cs in this case is not link with the aspx page. It is only a random .cs class in the App_Code repository in a Web project.

Comment: If you are calling the class from the code-behind, just pass the request values that it needs as parameters. Your classes shouldn't have intimate knowledge of where the data comes from anyway, because what happens when you want to use the same class in a WPF or other type of project? The `Request` object wouldn't exist and your code isn't really reusable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming the `toto.cs` will always be used in conjunction with ASP.Net, you can use the `HttpContext` object to get the current context and access the `Request` as in the code behind of a page.

Something like `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ref"];`.

`HttpContext` is located in `System.Web`.

Comment: I add information. In this case toto.cs is not link with the .aspx page. So the HttpContext does not seems to be possibly called in the toto.cs

Comment: @Slayner As long as you're in ASP.NET in a request/response context, you can. You can get the current context via `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`. You may need to add an asssembly reference to `System.Web`.

Comment: @Slayner: yes it is, as long as the http request is active (i.e. have not returned) the information is available through the method in this answer.

Comment: Yes I just tried it, i was missing the using for system.web for the http.context to show of.

Comment: You may want to update your answer to explain that you either need to fully qualify where `HttpContext` class is, or add a `using` statement for the namespace.